# Consume SOAP Service from SpringBoot - @RequestBody getting null values

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, soap

I am getting null value for empID in RequestControllers RequestBody MyReq request. When I called Rest Service using below JSON Request.

```
{
   "EmpID": [
      "1111","1234"
   ]
}
```

This is my Controller

```
    @SpringBootApplication
        @RestController
        public class MessageProcessorApplication {
        @Autowired
            private SoapClient client;
            
            @RequestMapping(value = "/getIdDetails", method = RequestMethod.POST)
            public MyRsp invokeSoapClient(@RequestBody MyReq request)
            {
                
                return client.getIdDetails(request);
            }
        
            }
```

My SoapClient class

```
@Service
    public class SoapClient {
    @Autowired
    private Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller;

    private WebServiceTemplate template;
    
    public MyRsp getIdDetails(MyReq request)
    {
        template = new WebServiceTemplate(marshaller);
        MyRsp response = (MyRsp) template.marshalSendAndReceive("http://localhost:8080/ws",request);
        return response;
    }
    }
```

jaxb generated MyReq and EmpID classes from SOAP Service WSDL

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "empID"
    })
    @XmlRootElement(name = "MyReq")
    public class MyReq
        extends BaseReq
    {
    
        @XmlElement(name = "EmpID", required = true)
        protected List<EmpID> empID;
    
        public void setEmpID(List<EmpID> empID) {
            this.empID = empID;
        }
        public List<EmpID> getEmpID() {
            if (empID == null) {
                empID = new ArrayList<EmpID>();
            }
            return this.empID;
        }
    
    }
    
    }
```

generated EmpID class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "value"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "EmpID")
public class EmpID {

    @XmlValue
    protected String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

I have tried with empID also in JSON Request. Still null values I am getting.

Comment: How is JSON related to SOAP? You are using a classic SOAP approach in your client, while you have a JSON server part. That is obviously never going to work.

Answer (score 1):

You may be running into [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40874820/xmlelementname-custom-name-not-working-in-spring-boot-integrated-with-rest-s). You also need to pass the value of EmpID in the constructor.

I can get your example to work if I change your generated classes to...

**MyReq.java**

```
package com.example.demo;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.util.List;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "MyReq")
public class MyReq
{
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected List<EmpID> empIds;

    public List<EmpID> getEmpIds() {
        return empIds;
    }

    public void setEmpIds(List<EmpID> empIds) {
        this.empIds = empIds;
    }
}
```

**EmpID.java**

```
package com.example.demo;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class EmpID {

    public EmpID(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @XmlValue
    protected String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

You would then need to post your json as...

```
{
    "empIds": ["1111","1234"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this json request.

```
{
    "empID": [
        {
            "value": "111"
        },
        {
            "value": "222"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Tried. Still the same..null value EmpID in the controller.

Comment: {
    "empID": [
        {
            "value": "111"
        },
        {
            "value": "222"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: This worked  @Holinc ..! what made it different than the previous request?

Comment: The requestBody value should be map to the `MyReq`. You can output the `MyReq` as json string if you don't know how to write it.